# curve fitting problems in R

Tags: r

I just have a quick question here as I am new to the R language. I do not feel like this code is right for curve fitting: The poly fit definitely checks out, but the log and exponential fit I am unsure of (e fit is def wrong). Any help would be appreciated , thanks. -Sam

```
polyFit <- function(xs,ys,degree) { #polynomial fitting a data set degree 3
  fit3 <- lm(ys~poly(xs,degree,raw=TRUE))
  xx <- seq(0,160, length=50)
  plot(xs,ys,pch='@')
  lines(xx, predict(fit3, data.frame(xs=xx)), col="green")
}

logFit <- function(xs,ys) { #graph the data set with log(x), y
  logEstimate = lm(ys ~ log(xs))
  plot(xs,ys,pch='@')
      lines(xs,predict(logEstimate),col='green')
    }

eFit <- function(xs,ys) {
  logEstimate = lm(log(ys) ~ xs)
  plot(xs,ys,pch='@')
  lines(xs,predict(logEstimate),col='green')
}
```

for clarification, xs = x points, ys = y points

Comment: I think your models are fine. Probably your issue is that you're not transforming your predictions. For example, in your `eFit`, you predict the `log(ys)`, and plot them against the `ys`. Probably you should plot the `exp(predict(logEstimate))`.

Comment: so like this?: eFit <- function(xs,ys) {
  logEstimate = lm(log(ys) ~ xs)
  plot(xs,ys,pch='@')
  lines(predict(logEstimate),ys,col='green')
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, like this:

```
eFit <- function(xs,ys) {
  expEstimate = lm(log(ys) ~ xs)
  plot(xs, ys,pch='@')
  lines(xs, exp(predict(expEstimate)),col='green')
}
```

I changed the model name just to make it clearly distinct from your `logFit` function, even though it's internal to the function. In that model, you fit the `log(y)`, so you predict the `log(y)`, so if you want to see how your prediction stack up against the real `y`, you need to untransform them, and `exp(log(y)) = y`.